# pandasで任意の位置の値に代入locの利用方法について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Pythonのpandasのライブラリを使って
任意の位置の値に代入したいです。

ExcelからYahooの交通費検索して取得した金額の値を
金額の列に値を入力したいです。
既に入力しているもの除外しております。

**Excel Data**

| 出発 | 到着 | 金額 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 東京 | 品川 |  |  |
| 池袋 | 浅草 |  |  |
| 新宿 | 五反田 | 168 | 20211222利用済み |

**実現結果のExcel Data**

| 出発 | 到着 | 金額 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 東京 | 品川 | 168 |  |
| 池袋 | 浅草 | 336 |  |
| 新宿 | 五反田 | 168 | 20211222利用済み |

下記の方法で行いましたが、
金額の列に上手く代入できないです。

どのように修正すれば良いか。教えていただけますか。

調べながらやっておりますので、locの代入指定のところがおかしいと思います。
現在下記の結果になります。

```
#取得した値を金額列へ入力
df.loc['金額'] = kingaku
```

****現在結果**

| 出発 | 到着 | 金額 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 東京 | 品川 |  |  |
| 池袋 | 浅草 |  |  |
| 336 | 336 | 336 | 336 |

code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4.element import Comment
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#FILE読込
file_time= dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
filename="C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\test\\test.xlsx"

#エクセル読込
df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name ='test',dtype=str)

#空白の行のみ選択
df= df[df['金額'].isnull()]
print(df)

#出発の値読み込み
df_from = df["出発"]
#到着の値読み込み
df_to =  df["到着"]

#エクセルの長さ読み込み
df_cnt = len(df)

#headless background 
option = Options()
#option.add_argument('--headless')

#Getting Default Adapter failed error message
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

#strDate = dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

#路線情報（乗換案内・時刻表・路線図）
URL= "https://transit.yahoo.co.jp/"

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe",options=option)

for x in range(df_cnt):

 # Googleの検索TOP画面を開き、路線情報（乗換案内・時刻表・路線図）へ遷移
 driver.get(URL)
 
 #2秒待機
 time.sleep(2)
 
 #出発要素
 SearchfromTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('from')
 
 #到着要素
 SearchtoTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('to')
 
 #出発到着テキスト入力
 SearchfromTxt.send_keys(df_from[x])
 SearchtoTxt.send_keys(df_to[x])
 #検索
 SearchtoTxt.submit()
 
 #4秒待機
 time.sleep(4)

 #料金の安い順位をクリック
 yasui = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tabflt"]/li[3]/a')
 yasui.click()
 
 #金額取得
 kingaku=driver.find_element_by_class_name('fare').text.replace('円','').replace(',','')
 print(kingaku)
 
 #取得した値を金額列へ入力
 df.loc['金額'] = kingaku

 # EXCEL保存  
 df.to_excel(filename,sheet_name="test",header=True,index=False)
 
 #繰り返し----------------------------------------------------------------
```

もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas documentation には
[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

rows と columns でアクセス, と記されています。

なので,

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
csv = io.StringIO('''
出発,到着,金額
東京,品川,
池袋,浅草,
新宿,五反田,
''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df_from = df["出発"]
df_to =  df["到着"]

df.loc[df_from == '池袋', '金額'] = 123
display(df)#print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | 出発 | 到着 | 金額 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 東京 | 品川 | nan |
| 1 | 池袋 | 浅草 | 123 |
| 2 | 新宿 | 五反田 | nan |

---

##### 追記

オリジナルデータを残したまま加工したい場合は

- もとの DataFrameを更新せず, その都度データ選別行うか
- 別の変数に DataFrameをセットする

```py
display(df[df['金額'].isnull()])
# あるいは
dfnull = df[df['金額'].isnull()]
display(dfnull)
```

保存時にファイルを上書きしないようにするには `df.to_excel` で
新規ファイル名を指定するか,
あるいはシート名を変えるとよいでしょう

Comment: 上記の方法でできました。ありがとうございます。ただ下記の方法で行うとファイルが上書き保存され、既に金額が入力されている行が削除されます。上書き保存されずに既に金額が入力されている行をそのまま残すにはどのように指定すれば分かりますでしょうか。`#書き込み df.loc[df_from == df_from[x], '金額'] = kingaku``# EXCEL保存  df.to_excel(filename,sheet_name="test",header=True,index=False)`

Comment: すでに金額が入ってる項目は, `df= df[df['金額'].isnull()]` の代入によって消されているので, その処理を行わなければ残ります。ファイルの上書きを行わないようにするなら, 新規のファイル名を指定すると OK

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方法でやってみます